# CORS Error using oidc-client in React SPA with ADFS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openid-connect, adfs

At a loss here, trying to do authorization code flow with `oidc-client` and `redux-oidc`, in my React app against an ADFS instance as the authorization server. My issue is that I am failing to post to `.../adfs/oauth2/token` with the authorization code during my `SignInCallback`, visually Part D) in the Diagram [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1). Every attempt results in a CORS error appearing in my browser, tried on Chrome and Firefox, there is no preflight check and I can see the `id_token`, `access_token`, and `refresh_token` in the response.

I can post from postman to that endpoint with no CORS error. The only workaround I've found was using a browser extension to allow CORS but this isn't suited for production. Why is my browser doing this?

My Config:

```
import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc';

export const config = {
  authority: process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_AUTHORITY,
  client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_REDIRECT_URI,
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  loadUserInfo: false
};

const userManager = createUserManager(config);
export default userManager;
```

My sign in callback:

```
 /* Imports above */
const SignInCallback = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const successCallback = user => {
    console.log(user);
    history.push('/DashboardDefault');
  };

  const errorCallback = error => {
    console.log(error);
    history.push('/LandingPage');
  };

  return (
    <CallbackComponent
      userManager={userManager}
      successCallback={successCallback}
      errorCallback={errorCallback}>
      <div className="text-center">Redirecting...</div>
    </CallbackComponent>
  );
};

export default connect()(SignInCallback);
```

My Request body:

```
client_id   "XXXXXXXXXX"
code    "XXXXXXX"
redirect_uri    "https://localhost:3001/callback"
code_verifier   "XXXXXXXXXX"
grant_type  "authorization_code"
```

My response body:

```
access_token    "XXXXXXXXX"
token_type  "bearer"
expires_in  3600
resource    "urn:microsoft:userinfo"
refresh_token   "XXXXXXXXX"
refresh_token_expires_in    21192
scope   "openid"
id_token    "XXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: In the authorization code flow it's the server that posts to the token endpoint. By "client" on your diagram they mean the server app, not the user agent. I doubt you ever get the cors response then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are missing standard CORS headers in the response - namely  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, and therefore, because the response is not in your SPA's domain, the browser cannot read it.

In [ADFS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs) there are some ways to customize the behaviour.

If this doesn't work for you then another option is to use a [Back End for Front End API](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/09/spa-back-end-for-front-end/) to proxy certain requests for you. Note also that this approach is recommended in 2021 for SPAs anyway.

Comment: Yeah this seems like the solution. Back End for Front End seems like it would only bring more complexity. I'll refer to the ADFS docs and get the headers sorted. Thank you.